# What are the reporting services in SharePoint 2013? What is difference between PerformancePoint, PowerPivot & Powerview reporting services?

Tags: powerpivot, performancepoint, powerview

Since first time got an opportunity to work on reporting services and new to it. Want to know that what are the reporting services. What is the difference between them. What is the actual use of it. How do they relate to sharepoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reporting Services**:
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Reporting Services is a server-based reporting platform that provides a full range of ready-to-use tools and services to help you create, deploy, and manage reports for your organization, as well as programming features that enable you to extend and customize your reporting functionality. You can integrate your reporting environment with a SharePoint product or technology to experience the benefits of using the collaborative environment provided by SharePoint sites.

[Reporting Services with SharePoint Integration](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210649(v=sql.105).aspx)

This section of the review is really about the strengths and tradeoffs between the aforementioned four technologies:

- SSRS is particularly robust around report distribution options and is
  probably easiest to scale for a large deployment. It has become
  comoditized in terms of the skill set
- PerformancePoint is a great fit for a shop that is trying to
  integrate structured and unstructured content for a seemless
  experience. The only real drawback (other than requiring some user
  training for end users) is the fact that this technology does not
  seem like it has gotten much love from Microsoft.  Although Microsoft
  has been very vocal about stressing the strategic importance of
  PerformancePoint on is BI stack, one can clearly see that PPS has not
  changed my in five years.  Also there is a very limited ability to
  customize the look and feel of the reports and dashboards which is
  very unfortunate.
- PowerView is a great product. Takes little time to learn and
  interact, and the visualizations look great. There are,
  unfortunately, a couple of areas of concern:

  - SilverLight – does not run on anything other than Windows
  - Poor SharePoint integration. PowerView is meant to occupy the entire page which makes it impossible to expose PowerView content along side with other web part in a SharePoint page.

read more here: [CHOOSING BETWEEN PERFORMANCEPOINT, POWERVIEW, EXCEL SERVICES AND REPORTING SERVICES FOR YOUR DATA VISUALIZATIONS](http://businessintelligist.com/2012/04/02/comparing-performancepoint-powerview-excel-services-and-reporting-services/)

Also check: [Choosing the Right Microsoft Reporting Technology Part 5: Power View](http://devinknightsql.com/2012/04/17/choosing-the-right-microsoft-reporting-technology-part-5-power-view/)

[PowerView vs. PowerPivot vs. Power BI](http://www.microsofttrends.com/2014/02/15/powerview-vs-powerpivot-vs-power-bi/)